# Image resources in shared GWT modules (widgets like)

Tags: gwt

I have many classes in GWT that represents graphical `widgets`. They are packaged as a `GWT` module called `GWT-Toolbox`. This module only have for now, client code. That means, all those classes are mainly layouts, windows, that I reuse along my others `GWT-apps` (separate modules).

For the moment, the way I'm doing this is that all my others `GWT-apps` inherits this `GWT-Toolbox` module.

*Is it the right way of doing it ?*

My main question is about `images resources`. I want to use in the `GWT-Toolbox` module, some images that would be shared along all `GWT-apps`.

What can I achieve that ? I don't want to use `ClientBundle` because it do not fit my needs.

*Where do I put my resources files, and how they will be packaged in the `GWT-apps` ?*

For the record, I'm using GWT 2.4

### EDIT

So, with the help of the community, I figured out how to proceed. Note, that this solution doesn't use `ClientBundle`.

**GWT-Toolbox** - this is the files structure

-src/main/java
--- com.mypackage.toolbox
------ public
--------- images
------------ img1.png
------------ img2.png
--------- GWT-Toolbox.gwt.xml

Inside GWT-Toolbox source code, refer to this images like this :

```
GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "images/img1.png"
```

and that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it the right way of doing it?

Absolutely; this is actually no different from widgets the live in the `com.google.gwt.user.User` module.
(provided *inherits* means `<inherits/>`, and putting the GWT-Toolbox JAR in the classpath)

> Where do I put my resources files, and how they will be packaged in the GWT-apps ?

You can either put them as simple resources in your JAR so that other modules can use them with `ClientBundle` by providing their path in `@Source`.
Or you an put them in a `public` subfolder (to be exact, the *public path* of your module, the subfolder name defaults to `public` but is actually configurable) of your module so they're deployed side-by-side with the `*.cache.*` compiled files (this is how *themes* work in GWT).

Comment: Great. Worked as expected. I see some strange, but perhaps normal thing. In my GWT-app war file, I now have the GWT-appName/images folder (from GWT-Toolbox) - which is great, and a /images folder (at root) which contains the images used by the GWT-app only. Is is normal ?

Comment: Yes (I suppose). Everything in `GWT-appName` comes from the modules' _public path_ and the output of the GWT compiler. The sibling `images` is (I suppose) one that you have in your _war folder_.