# multiple GWT modules in IntelliJ IDEA and 404 errors

Tags: gwt, intellij-idea

There's an application written in GWT which consists of many modules. There is a main module which is an "entry point" to the application. Lets call it *Foo-Main* And there are few additional modules: *Foo-Styles*, *Foo-Icons*, etc. - each one of them has only some content in `src/main/webapp` (like `.css` files) that should be available in the application.

And I'm trying to make it work in IntelliJ IDEA.

I created an artifact, `src/main/webapp` are added as source folders, I added every *GWT compiler output* from other modules to the artifact. When I try to run GWT Dev Mode, content from `src/main/webapp` of *Foo-Main* module is available, but not from other modules - and I get 404 errors e.g. on stylesheets.

What am I missing in the configuration?

EDIT:

More details as requested in comment:

```
[WARN] 404 - GET /Styles/gxt/css/gxt-all.css (127.0.0.1) 1412 bytes
   Request headers
      Host: 127.0.0.1:8888
      Connection: keep-alive
      User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.79 Safari/537.1
      Accept: text/css,*/*;q=0.1
      Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
      Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
      Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
      Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8888/Foo-Main/index.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997
```

And content of `src/main/webapp/` in *Foo-Styles* looks like this:

```
src/
    main/
        webapp/
            ...
            gxt/
                chart/
                    ...
                css/
                    gxt-all.css
                    gxt-gray.css
                ...
            ...
```

Additionally, in *Foo-Main* it looks like this:

```
src/
    main/
        webapp/
            Foo-Main/
                ...
                Styles/
                    foo-main.css
                ...
                help.html
                index.html
```

Comment: I have a small clue about your problem. Please post the `404 errors` output with also what's precisely inside `src/main/webapp`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at a question I've asked :

[Image resources in shared GWT modules (widgets like)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737674/image-resources-in-shared-gwt-modules-widgets-like)

I'm sure it will help you ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in IDEA. It will be fixed in the next IDEA 12 EAP build